ImportError when attempting to create a header using borb PDF library in Python
I'm trying to create a header in a PDF document using the borb library in Python. However, I'm encountering an ImportError when attempting to import the necessary modules. Here's my code:
from borb.pdf import Page
from borb.pdf import Document
from borb.pdf import MultiColumnLayout
from borb.pdf import PageLayout
from borb.pdf.canvas.layout.layout_element import Container, Span

# Further code to create header and add content

The error message I'm getting is:
ImportError: cannot import name 'Container' from 'borb.pdf.canvas.layout.layout_element'

I've tried various import statements, but I can't seem to get past this error. Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong and how I can correctly import these modules to create a header in my PDF document using borb?

The word "Container" does not exist anywhere in the borb repository.  What made you think it did?  Why did you choose borb?  There are other well-established PDF libraries.

@TimRoberts ChatGPT suggested the code with the Container component. I did go through a lot of PDF libraries in Python but settled with this at the moment due to extensive documentation with examples, adding graphics and images, ability to define single/multi-layout where I do not have to provide the co-ordinates explicitly like pyfpdf. I will be open to any suggestions for an open-source PDF library but need to create raw PDFs from scratch with no external dependencies like wkhtmltopdf

My favorite is reportlab.  I've used them for more than 20 years.  They have both a low-level canvas-based model, and a "flow" based model that works more like a word processor.  They also have a commercial version that is a full-fledged report writer; I've never used that.

The documentation is pretty old and the syntax is also camel case suggesting it is not actively maintained. But I will give it a try and see. Thanks!

There is a company behind ReportLab that maintains it actively, funded by their commercial product.  They have their own mailing lists.  And PDFs are not changing; once the product works, what changes do you need?

Right! While I am exploring it, can you share some useful resources where I can find some PDF templates built using reportlab?

Their code repo (in Mercurial) includes a number of samples.  There are 50 or 60 relatively focused test scripts, and there's a script for generating the product documentation.  And here's git gist I wrote for generating Avery labels: https://gist.github.com/timrprobocom/3946aca8ab75df8267bbf892a427a1b7

@TimRoberts On the contrary, PDF is still a changing format. Whilst the original spec (ISO 32000) was developed in 1992, the latest version (ISO 32000-2:2020) dates from December 2020. Furthermore, I can imagine that specific authors/companies might emphasize different qualities in their respective codebases. Pertaining to borb, I put a lot of emphasis on documentation, ease of use, and testing.

disclaimer: I am the author of the borb library
chatGPT is not always able to generate working code. In this case, it invented a class Container, which does not exist in borb.
Depending on what you want to do precisely, you should check out the other implementations of LayoutElement.
